# Mongodb / Jongo sorting then limit, vs, limit then sorting

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

Are these two guaranteed to be the same:

```
collection.limit(10).sort("{score: -1}")
```

vs

```
collection.sort("{score: -1}").limit(10)
```

The second one does a global sort, and returns the top 10. Is the first one guaranteed to do the same, or may it just return 10 sorted records?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal queries, `sort` is processed first, then `skip`, and then `limit`, no matter in which order you add them to your cursor object.

The aggregation framework will execute the `$sort`, `$skip` and `limit` operators in their order of appearance in the pipeline.